# Batch update in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have a data set which is stored in the following manner

Category Object

```
{
    "categoryId": "Cat_1",
    "image": "",
    "name": "Category 1",
    "visibility":"true",
    "products": [
        {
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/Emj29FB.jpg",
            "name": "Product 1",
            "price": "20",
            "productId": "Prd_1"
        },
        {
            "image": "https://i.imgur.com/M76HRKT.jpg",
            "name": "Product 2",
            "price": "10",
            "productId": "Prd_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Product 1 Object

```
{
     "image": "https://i.imgur.com/Emj29FB.jpg",
     "name": "Product 1",
     "price": "20",
     "productId": "Prd_1",
     "categoryId": "CAT_xYFcMR5oxG"
}
```

Product 2 Object

```
{
     "image": "https://i.imgur.com/Emj29FB.jpg",
     "name": "Product 2",
     "price": "10",
     "productId": "Prd_2",
     "categoryId": "CAT_xYFcMR5oxG"
}
```

I have a requirement to disable categories, and when I do that I need to remove the category reference from the product object, to do that I need to separately update each product is there a way to update the products as a batch? The final objects after update should look something like below.

Category Object

```
{
    "categoryId": "Cat_1",
    "image": "",
    "name": "Category 1",
    "visibility":"false",
    "products": []
}
```

Product 1 Object

```
{
     "image": "https://i.imgur.com/Emj29FB.jpg",
     "name": "Product 1",
     "price": "20",
     "productId": "Prd_1",
     "categoryId": ""
}
```

Product 2 Object

```
{
     "image": "https://i.imgur.com/Emj29FB.jpg",
     "name": "Product 2",
     "price": "10",
     "productId": "Prd_2",
     "categoryId": ""
}
```

Comment: can you add your chaincode?

Comment: Is this real data?  I ask because if not, why not just start over using the data format you want?  There's no built-in concept of a "batch" update.  Given you will need to update your chaincode, you could implement the logic to read the current category record, loop though the products creating new records and deleting the product from categories in the "Init" method

Comment: @Gari Yes.this is real data for a project that im working